# Bash script insert numbers

Tags: bash, unix

I am trying to write a bash script to call the three following commands:

```
./clean -a
./configure
./compile em_real &> compile.log &
```

However, in the `./configure` command asks the user to type in a number twice, for example:

```
Enter selection [1-63] :
```

How can I let the bash script automatically fill in the numbers I want? I figured this would be quite easy to do but my search on the internet did not pay off.

Comment: Incorrect tag. Batch-file is not batch processing.

Comment: @Dominique make complete edits please, was forced to reject on behalf of the Community member.

Comment: I am sorry, I am not that experienced with these languages. I have made an edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a *here document*:

```
./configure  << __END__
first string
second string
__END__
```

Note that the terminating label, I have used `__END__`, must not be indented or preceded by any other characters on that line.

For your specific case of entering the same number twice, you could use something like this:

```
num=42
./configure  << __END__
$num
$num
__END__
```